# Formatting databound asp.net dropdown

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net webpage with a drop down menu that is populated by a databound list that pulls it's entries (dates) from a database.

I have this part working and displaying the correct information, but the thing is that it displays the dates as mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM.  Ideally, I would like it to display as mm/yyyy (even just mm/dd/yyyy would be ok).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In ASP.NET, how can I force the format of dates in a DropDownList to "DD/MM/YYYY"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654250/in-asp-net-how-can-i-force-the-format-of-dates-in-a-dropdownlist-to-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to do it in the Select statement - use the Convert() function (assuming the DB is SQL Server)

```
Select Convert(varchar, MyDateField, 101) AD MyDateField
```

Usage and different formats (alternatives to "101" in the example above) can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Alternately, you can use the DataTextFormatString property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextformatstring.aspx

and set it to "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

Answer (score 2):

You can try this in your code behind:

```
dropdownlistname.DataTextFormatString ="{0:MM/yyyy}"
```

or in the aspx form:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropdownlistname" 
                  runat="server"
                  DataTextFormatString='{0:MM/yyy}'......>
```