# How to change the data format for the current culture so that it applies to the entire web application

Tags: asp.net, globalization, date-formatting

I would like to set the date format to '**YYYY-MM-DD**' for my entire web application. I can do this by creating an object of `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` and then registering it. But since my application is on a **hosted environment**, I cannot run executables to register the culture.

I need a way to do this within the `Application_Start` so that it applies to the entire web app.

I tried changing the date format using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`, but it does not seem to propagate the change to the entire application.

In short, I need a way to change current culture settings of the entire web application programatically from with in the web app itself.

**Edit:** I tried the following on suggestion of @doitgood, but got exception `System.InvalidOperationException: Instance is read-only.`, while the intellisense shows the property as Get or Set.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";   
}
```

To make the change global to the application I tried the following in `Application_Start`:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

I get the same exception 'Instance is read-only'.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Sebeto is correct. I had the same problem and I just tried it. Thought I'd add some more explanation. The current culture's properties are indeed read-only once the current culture has been set. You must therefore construct a new CultureInfo object (easiest way is by cloning the existing culture). Then, you can tweak the culture info object's properties before swapping the current threads culture object with your own.

```
CultureInfo newCultureDefinition = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
//make percentages n% instead of n % .ToString("p") adds a space by default english culture in asp.net
newCultureDefinition.NumberFormat.PercentPositivePattern = 1;
newCultureDefinition.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCultureDefinition;
```

There is also the question of *where* to put the code to change the current thread's culture.

According to Microsoft's example, see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162 you can even change the current culture on Page_Load. Since you might have code that needs your formatting before Page_Load, I have put my change in my base page OnInit.

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
        initGlobalCulturalFormattingChanges();
}
```

and to cap it off:

```
private void initGlobalCulturalFormattingChanges()
{

    CultureInfo newCultureDefinition = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    //make percentages n% instead of n % (.ToString("p0") adds a space by default in asp.net
    newCultureDefinition.NumberFormat.PercentPositivePattern = 1;
    newCultureDefinition.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCultureDefinition;

}
```

Is it the best idea to swap out the current Thread's culture with every request one every page's init? I don't have enough data to weigh in on that but it seems to work ok :).

Answer (score 4):

> got exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: Instance is read-only.', while the intellisense shows the property as Get or Set.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern ="yyyy-MM-dd";
```

You can't directly change the things in Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture apparently, I got the same problem.

But you can do it like this:

```
CultureInfo TempCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
TempCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern ="yyyy-MM-dd";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = TempCulture;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do this on `application_start`, only the thread that started the application will be effected.

You need to ensure the change happens on every request - an `HttpModule` that sets this for every request is probably the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Cant you put your code into global.asax `Application_BeginRequest` event and update appropriate `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?