# CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern Read-Only

Tags: c#, datetime, time, format, readonly

I'm trying to set LongTimePattern property of CurrentCulture with the following code:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
```

and I'm getting InvalidOperationException:
Instance is read-only.

Any idea how can I change it? I want to force `LongTimePattern` to show 24h format for any culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you change the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture then it will automatically update the LongTimePattern.

You can't make any updation in current assigned culture info but create a new one and assign it to current culture.

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo c = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
c.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "h-mm-ss";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = c;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to change ONE or TWO values and keep the rest the same, you can use Clone to get a writable copy of the current culture, eg:

```
CultureInfo i;
i = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
i.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
i.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = i;
i = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Clone();
i.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
i.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = i;
```

This seems better than having to use a culture string to get your starting culture.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can change the cultures, allowing you to do so would defeat the purpose of having cultures in the first place - they should show the date and time in the commonly accepted format used by that culture.

If you wish to show a different format, then you can always use a custom date/time formatter.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx for all available pre-set formats, and details on how to display your own format.