# How to format the dates that appear in Html.DropDownListFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an object:

```
class Milk {
    public DateTime ExpirationDate {get;set;}
    ...
}
```

In a collection in a model:

```
class GroceryModel {
    public IList<Milk> Milks {get;set;}
    public Milk SelectedMilk {get;set;}
}
```

And I'm populating a dropdown list using Razor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ExpirationDate, Model.Milks, ...);
```

How can I format the dates that appear in that dropdown list?

Comment: Review this questions, it may helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654250/in-asp-net-how-can-i-force-the-format-of-dates-in-a-dropdownlist-to-dd-mm-yyyy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your controller:

model.SelectMilk will hold a list of SelectListItems

```
        model.SelectMilk =
            Milks.Select(
                item =>
                new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Selected = false, 
                        Value = item.ExpirationDate , 
                        Text = datetime.ToShortDateString() //or whatever format you need
                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try annotating the property with:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```