# Formatting a TimeSpan without turning it to a string

Tags: c#, timespan

Is there anyway to format a TimeSpan object without using this approach:

```
TimeSpan timeSpan = new TimeSpan(1,1,0);

var formattedTimeSpan = timeSpan.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
```

The purpose of asking this question is that I actually want to do the above but without ending up with a string; as I still need to work with the formatted output as a `TimeSpan` rather than a String. Casting it back to a `TimeSpan` after formatting it defaults it back to the unwanted format of `hh:mm:ss`.

**Update in reply to @Idle_Mind  to show underpinnings of the questions:**

This is all in an MVC project. I am trying to generate a Time picker dropdownlist, which are to be used in a @Html.DropDownListFor tag..

The problem is that the dropdownlist items are being displayed in the format of hh:mm:ss. I do not want to format it with a ToString() because I do not want to change the model property type from TimeSpan to String. The property needs to remain maintained in its original type of TimeSpan, or otherwise there will be a lot of regressions to doing that change.

**OK - Coding talk is here:**

This is how I am generating the dropdownlist items:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides a listItems of opening hours to use in an HTML DropDownListFor helper. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="slotObject"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static List<SelectListItem> GetOpeningHours(TimeSpan time)
{
    // These could be later exposed in the webconfig if needed.
    var startTime = new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0);
    var closingTime = new TimeSpan(22,0,0);
    var incrementer = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);

    var timesList = new List<TimeSpan>();

    var newTime = startTime.Add(incrementer);

    for (TimeSpan i = startTime; i<closingTime; i+=incrementer)
    {
        timesList.Add(TimeSpan.Parse(i.Add(incrementer).ToString(@"hh\:mm")));
    }

    return GetDropDownList(timesList, time);
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets List Items in Text only, instead of a combination of text and value.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="selectOptions"></param>
/// <param name="selectedOption"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownList(List<TimeSpan> selectOptions, TimeSpan selectedOption)
{
    var listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();

    foreach (var option in selectOptions)
    {
        listItems.Add(new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = option.ToString(),
            Selected = TimeSpan.Compare(option, selectedOption) == 0
        });
    }
    return listItems;
}
```

**This is how I am using it in Razor**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StartFrom, Website.ViewModels.ViewHelpers.OpeningTimesList.GetOpeningHours(Model.StartFrom), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**This is how it is displaying:**

[image]

**The problem again:**

I wanted to stop this ugly display. I am now thinking to update the code above to display two items: one for the DropdownListItem Text (which contains the formatted string in a string format), and another for Value, which is actually the TimeSpan - I think this should work but let me know if it wont; I'd be grateful.

I will update this with the outcome.

Many thanks.

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense, before its formatted its just data in a "computer" format. It doesn't make sense to work with it in a "formatted" manner. Maybe if you said what you are trying to do we can help.

Comment: What "work" is causing the issue?  Can you show us the code that is failing?  It appears that you are trying to get rid of the seconds portion of the TimeSpan.  Are seconds somehow causing a problem in your code?

Comment: Regarding your update, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/14606458/993547. You have to create `SelectListItem` by hand.

Comment: @Idle_Mind please see my update in reply. thanks..

Comment: You lost me there as I don't do web stuff...but that should definitely be enough information for someone else to provide a solution!  The reason I asked is this sounded like a classic [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/227172)  candidate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "format" an object. Formatting happens when printing. So just keep using your `timeSpan` instance wherever you want a `TimeSpan`, and finally call `.ToString()` to format-print it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that. The `TimeSpan` is just a `struct` containing some data, integers. A `TimeSpan` will always have `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds`, etc. A `TimeSpan` contains no formatting at all (you can see some when debugging, but that is just magic... it calls `ToString` to visualize the data).

If you want to format it, you have to put it `ToString()`. That will make it... a `string`. Converting it back to a `TimeSpan` will yield `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` again.

If you think those `Seconds` aren't useful to you, and you really want to get rid of them, create your own implementation of a `TimeSpanWithoutSeconds` based on the [Reference Source of `TimeSpan`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timespan.cs).